# Constrained optimisation with function in the constraint and binary variable

Tags: r, optimization

I am looking for a way to solve - in R - a constrained optimisation problem of the form

```
min sum(x)

s.t. f(x) < k
```

where x is a binary variable (either 0 or 1) with lenght n, and f(x) is a function that depends on the entire x variable, and k is an integer constant. Thus, f(x) is not a set of n constraints to each value of x (such as sqrt(x)), but a constraint that is met based on the entire set of values of the binary variable x.

I have tried to use ompr R package with the following syntax

```
v < 1:10
result <- MILPModel() %>%
add_variable(x[i], i = 1:v, type = "binary") %>%
set_objective(sum_expr(x[i], i = 1:v), sense = "min") %>%
add_constraint(f(x) <= 60) %>%
solve_model(with_ROI(solver = "glpk"))
```

but it does not work, because I believe the package does not accept a global f(x) constraint.

Comment: `f(x)` makes the model nonlinear. OMPR only supports linear models.

Comment: Any concrete code and package suggestion to solve the problem?

Comment: What is the function `f` ? Could you edit your post to provide a fully reproducible example ?

Comment: The function is rather complex, I would avoid posting it. For the toy example here proposed, let's assume it is sd(x).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with the `rgenoud` package.

```
library(rgenoud)

g <- function(x){
  c(
    ifelse(sd(x) > 0.2, 0, 1), # set the constraint (here sd(x)>0.2) in this way
    sum(x) # the objective function (to minimize/maximize)
  )
}

solution <- genoud(
  g, lexical = 2,
  nvars = 30, 
  starting.values = rep(0, 30), 
  Domains = cbind(rep(0,30), rep(1,30)),
  data.type.int = TRUE)

solution$par # the values of x
## [1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
sd(solution$par) # is the constraint satisfied ?
## [1] 0.2537081
solution$value
## [1] 0 2 ; 0 is the value of ifelse(sd(x)>0.2,0,1) and 2 is the value of sum(x)
```

See the **Notes** section in `?genoud` to understand the `lexical` argument.