# How to create binary constraints for optimization in R?

Tags: r, optimization

I have a function f(x) which I intend to minimize. "x" is a vector containing 50 parameters. This function has several constraints: first is that all parameters in x should be binary, so that x = (1,1,0,1,...); second is that the sum of "x" should be exactly 25, so that sum(x) = 25. The question can be illustrated as:

min f(x)

s.t. sum(x) = 25,
x = 0 or 1

However when I try to solve this problem in R, I met some problems. Prevalent packages such as "optim","constrOptim" from "stats" can only input coefficients of the target function (in my case, the function is bit complex and cannot be simply illustrated using coefficient matrix), "donlp2" from "Rdonlp" does not support setting parameters to be binary. I'm wondering whether anyone has any idea of how to set binary constraints for this case?

Comment: You need an MINLP solver for this (MINLP=Mixed Integer Non-Linear Programming).

Comment: Could you please remind me the package name which could solve this problem?

Comment: Most likely that depends on how f(x) looks like.

Comment: [RMiniZinc](https://github.com/acharaakshit/RMiniZinc) would be an option, but it is complicated to setup, has some very specific dependencies and a steep learning curve. See [MiniZinc](https://www.minizinc.org/) for background.

Comment: You might try a simple Local Search, see for instance this tutorial https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3391756 which relies on package `NMOF` (https://cran.r-project.org/package=NMOF). [Disclosure: I am the maintainer.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding my comment, here is an example of a Local Search, as implemented in package [`NMOF`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=NMOF). (I borrow Stéphane's objective function).

```
library("NMOF")
library("neighbours")

## Stéphane's objective function
f <- function(x)
    sum(1:20 * x)

nb <- neighbourfun(type = "logical", kmin = 10, kmax = 10)

x0 <- c(rep(FALSE, 10), rep(TRUE, 10))
sol <- LSopt(f, list(x0 = x0, neighbour = nb, nI = 1000))

## initial solution
as.numeric(x0)
## [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

## final solution
as.numeric(sol$xbest)
## [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

(Disclosure: I am the maintainer of packages [`NMOF`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=NMOF) and [`neighbours`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=neighbours).)

Comment: Thank you! It works well on my function!

Comment: That sounds like good packages (+1). Is it possible to use them to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57852907/1100107) as well?

Comment: Thanks. Not as easily: `neighbours` handles constraints by always staying feasible: start with a feasible solution, and then create successive neighbours that remain feasible. It would be hard to provide a generic implementation that works for any `f` in the constraints. But instead one could handle it via a penalty term, to be added in the objective function. This would, in effect, transform the problem into an unconstrained one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the amazing package **rgenoud**. Below is an example.

I take 20 binary variables instead of your 50 for easier reading. I take `f(x) = sum(1:20 * x)`, this is a weighted sum with increasing weights so clearly the best solution (restricted to sum(x)=10) is 1, 1, ..., 1, 0, 0, ..., 0. And **rgenoud** brilliantly finds it.

```r
library(rgenoud)

f <- function(x) { # the function to be minimized
  sum(1:20 * x)
}

g <- function(x){
  c(
    ifelse(sum(x) == 10, 0, 1), # set the constraint (here sum(x)=10) in this way
    f(x) # the objective function (to minimize/maximize)
  )
}

solution <- genoud(
  g, 
  pop.size = 3000,
  lexical = 2, # see ?genoud for explanations
  nvars = 20,  # number of x_i's
  starting.values = c(rep(0, 10), rep(1, 10)), 
  Domains = cbind(rep(0, 20), rep(1, 20)), # lower and upper bounds
  data.type.int = TRUE # x_i's are integer
)

solution$par # the values of x
## [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
solution$value
## [1] 0 55 ; 0 is the value of ifelse(sum(x)=10,0,1) and 55 is the value of f(x)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works well on my function! However I'm bit confused about how the constraint sum(x) = 10 is set? How does "genoud" recon the constraints and the object function?

Comment: @流淌的乐淘淘 genoud minimizes `ifelse(sum(x) == 10, 0, 1)`, the minimum is 0 when sum(x)=10